# Run ant exec task from different folder

Tags: deployment, ant, build, continuous-integration

I want to run my "exec grails" task into my grails project. I set grail path in exec task like

```
 <exec executable="${grails}"
```

How can I say , that exec should start from my project folder?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the [`exec` Ant task documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html):

```
Attribute    Description
dir          the directory in which the command should be executed.
```

```xml
<exec executable="${grails}" dir="${my.project.dir}">
```